# Animated movie - training in mountain area

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

Searching for an animated movie with the following hints

- should be the same age as "the last unicorn" or older
- pretty eastern, maybe chinese but it can also be western with a little inspiration. Not classic anime style (neither modern nor old like astro boy)
- there was training in an mountain area involved, the hero had to climb an unbelievable high mountain. I think I remember other trainings like carrying large buckets full of water
- whole atmosphere was darker, cannot remember many humans, maybe even some kind of ghost world
- saw it in the 80s as a child.. maybe 85
- it was well drawn for that time and not a childrens movie per se

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you watched it, or where/what studios? Or the names of any characters there might have been?

Comment: Seems unlikely that it would be *Three Monks*, but that came out in 1980 and involved mountains and water with a Chinese atmosphere. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Monks

Comment: If I asked, was the main character female and the mysterious trainer was her Grandfather prompt you in any way?

Comment: Edlothiad, you are right that is not a lot but since I saw it as a child (around 85) I really can remember so little.. but it was stuck in my head since then... will try to improve my question
@Fuzzy, three monks is not it, as far as I can remember it was very well drawn for that time and the atmosphere was rather dark

Comment: @Enigma, wow, that really can be... it could be a heroine! And there was a trainer involved.. do you know the title?

Comment: Then I will try to remember the series I think it is 2 or 3 seasons and they had to go to the mountains because they were basically ill trained.  Grand father sends them to the top of the mountain.  I think the female is part of a Ninja/assassin clan and can deal with fire attacks.  A male that left the clan returns and is different but they join forces vs the undead/unnatural beings being released.

Comment: You may want to look through this list "Kaze no Stigma (Stigma of the Wind)" was the one I was looking for and may be what your looking for, the write up seemed incomplete and the 23 episodes may have been or is 2 seasons.

Comment: I really think it was a move (but some series have been recut to a movie so can be) but the only "Kaze no stigma" I find was from 2007.. it was no classic anime though it can be japanese

Answer (score 6):

**金猴降妖
Monkey King Conquers the Demon, a.k.a. The Monkey King and the Skeleton Ghost   1984 - 1985**
[image: Movie cover art.]

The monkey king, Sun Wukong, is a well known folk tale from China. He is also referenced as a character in many games.

I couldn't find a version on youtube with English subtitles, though you might be able to understand the story without them, since they dont speak much.

Found by: Looking up age the age of "Last Unicorn", searching "Chinese movies animated 1980's", then examining the movies listed on Wikipedia that fit the query.

Comment: what an amazing find! Thanks for digging so deep! the background style really is damn close just the characters were less colorful and far more realistic.. but really good one!